# Acess to JSON file python if statement

Tags: python, json, selenium

I am trying to get access to the information in my JSON file in an if statement based on the user information in the JSON file. So I decided to test it by having it print a message to the console. However, it doesn't even read the JSON file at all.  Here is the JSON file

```
{
    "member_acct":{
       "email":"example@gmail.com",
       "password":"examplepassword"
    },
    "product_info":{
       "product_name":"Nike Airforce 1s",
       "W/M":"M",
       "size":"9.5"
    }
 }
```

Here is the python. I am using nested if statements I wonder if i can just combine those if statments:

```
json_data = json.load(f)

# Women's shoe sizes

a = json_data["product_info"]["W/M"]
if 'W' in a:
    print("This is a womens shoe")
    if 5 in json_data["product_info"]["size"]:
        print("size 5")
    else
        print("This is not a size 5")

// men sizes 
b = json_data["product_info"]["W/M"]
if "M" in b:
     print ("this is a men's shoe")
    if "3.5" in json_data["product_info"]["size"]:
      print ("3.5")
    else print ("this is not a size 3.5")
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do or ask. If "W/M" is not "W" what is the expected outcome for when the size is/isn't 5?

Comment: ok, so it's conventional because I have the same thing but for "M" sizes. But what its saying is like if 'W' is in 'a' then go to the if statement for "if 5 is in size" @ChadS. because i also have the same thing for the men size shoes. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've ran your code and it works just fine, excluding a missing ":" in your "else" statement. You need to load in your json file as a file object. So I assumed "f" variable is a file by doing "with open('data.json') as f:"

Comment: I would suggest that perhaps you want to make some functions to describe the product based on its info. Then the organization of your code can be made more modular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a JSON in a separate file, you will need to read the file in order to import in `with open('./data.json') as f`.  Also, `if 'W' in a` seems to be not correct as your JSON blob has that as a string and not an object `"W/M":"M"`.  so it would look something like:

`data.json`

```
{
    "member_acct":{
       "email":"example@gmail.com",
       "password":"examplepassword"
    },
    "product_info":{
       "product_name":"Nike Airforce 1s",
       "W/M":"M",
       "size":"9.5"
    }
 }
```

`main.py`

```
import json
    
with open('./data.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
        
  a = data["product_info"]["W/M"]
  # the value of a is a string and not a dictionary
  if a == 'W':
    print("This is a woman's shoe")
    # the value of this is a string and not a dictionary
    if float(data["product_info"]["size"]) == 5:
      print("size 5")
    else:
      print("This is not a size 5")
  else:
    print ("this is a men's shoe")
    if float(data["product_info"]["size"]) == 3.5:
      print("size 3.5")
    else:
      print("This is not a size 3.5")
```

note: edited, good catch, JSON size value is a float, not an int.  Adjusted to cast value to float